# syscall-template.S not found

Tags: c++, sockets, debugging, cross-compiling, system-calls

I am trying to debug my program for a project. I have to use breakpoints to point out blocking functions within my code. When i started the debugger and clicked on "Step into" i got the "syscall-template.S not found" message. I'm working in C++ within VS (I have to in this project), cross-compiling to a Pi4.

[image: Here the message with more info.]

As far as I understand it is looking for a file, but I don't know if that should be pre-installed, if it should be on the Pi or my laptop etc etc.

I have been searching around a bit on the internet and asked in some discords, sadly with no results that i found helpful. This is probably because I am pretty new to this and I do not understand the explanations I have come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo apt install gdb`?